# Cylinder with non circle bottom, TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

Hi i try to plot a cylindrical domain, where the bottom of the cylinder is not a circle or ellipse.

My knowledge is very poor and all my previous attempts failed.

Failed attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates{(0,0) (1,-.5) (1.2,1.5) (0,1) (-.5,.5) (-.7,.2)};

\draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates{(3,2) (4,1.5) (4.2,3.5) (3,3) (2.5,2.5) (2.3,2.2)};


\draw (1,-.5)--(4,1.5);

\draw (1.2,1.5)--(4.2,3.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you include your failed attempt too? It will help us to get the idea what you mean

Comment: Here it is, very poor

Comment: Can you also include a mock-up of what you are trying to achieve? It can be done with drawing software.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like asked in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136308/tikz-a-cylinder-of-infinite-height)?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

There are many ways to visualize such a cylinder in `TeX` world, here is one made by means of
`extrude` feature of the `Asymptote` using raster output.

```
% cyl.tex :
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="png";
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.render=8;
size(5cm);
import graph3;
import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(3,3,6),up=Z,target=O,zoom=1);

currentlight=light(gray(0.8),ambient=rgb(0.1,0.099,0.101),specular=gray(0.7),
                     specularfactor=3,viewport=true,dir(42,48));

pair[] ppair={(0,0),(1,-.5),(1.2,1.5),(0,1),(-.5,.5),(-.7,.2)};
real height=3;

guide gbase=graph(ppair, Spline)..cycle;

pen bpen=rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.8)+opacity(0.5);
material m=material(diffusepen=0.7bpen
,ambientpen=bpen,emissivepen=0.3*bpen,specularpen=0.999white,shininess=1.0);

draw(rotate(-90,Y)*rotate(180,Z)*extrude(gbase,height*Z),m,render(merge=true));

xaxis3("$x$",-3.2,1.2,red  ,Arrow3);
yaxis3("$y$",  -2,2,green,Arrow3);
zaxis3("$z$",  -3,3,blue ,Arrow3);

\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex cyl.tex    
% asy cyl-*.asy    
% pdflatex cyl.tex
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you could use *pgfplots* for this, e.g.:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [ z buffer=sort,
    ]
        \addplot3[domain=0:360,y domain=0:360,surf,shader=faceted,samples=40]
        ( {cos(y)+0.1*sin(7*y)},
            {x},
            {sin(y)+0.1*cos(3*y)}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A function for the base is also possible.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=50 -20 40 rtp2xyz, Decran=50,linearc=0.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(4,4)
\psSolid[object=prisme,axe=0 0.5 1,
base= 0 0 1 -.5 1.2 1.5 0 1 -.5 .5 -.7 .2 ,
linecolor=red,h=4,action=draw*]
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(4,4)
\psSolid[object=prisme,axe=0 0.5 1,
base= 0 0 1 -.5 1.2 1.5 0 1 -.5 .5 -.7 .2 ,
hollow,fillcolor=red!30,incolor=blue!30,
linecolor=red,h=4,action=draw**]%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Heart like base should be interesting.